# Stone-Weierstrass Theorem (Lattices)

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory, vector-lattices, weierstrass-approximation

I am struggling with a portion of a proof concerning the lattice version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

In particular, there is a subset $\mathcal{A}$ of the set of all real-valued continuous functions on a compact set $X$ such that if $f,g\in\mathcal{A}$ then $s\,f+g\in\mathcal{A}$ (where $s\in\mathbb{R}$) and $f\,g\in\mathcal{A.} $ Moreover, all constant functions are in $\mathcal{A}$.

I consider a function $g\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $\sup_{x\in X}|g(x)|\leq1$.
By an application of the Weierstrass approximation theorem, it holds true that for all $\delta>0$ there exists a polynomial $P(g)$ such that $$\sup_{g\in[-1,1]}\big||g|-P(g)\big|\leq\delta.$$ 
The proof now asserts that, since the constant functions are in $\mathcal{A}$, it follows that $P(\,g\,)\in\mathcal{A}.$

I am afraid, I do not see how this is true.
I would appreciate any help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the assertion is not true. Take $X=[-1,1]$ and 
$$
\mathcal A=\{\lambda 1 + f:\ f|_{[0,1]}=0\}. 
$$
Then $\mathcal A$ satisfies your conditions, and it contains no polynomials other than the constants.

---

**Edit:** with access to the [link](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/2010/3103_handout_5.pdf), it looks like you have misunderstood a few things. What happens is this:

- the algebra $\mathcal A$ is closed;
- lemma 5.10 guarantees that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $P_\varepsilon$ such that $$\tag{$*$}\sup_{s\in[-1,1]}|\,|s|-P_\varepsilon(s)|<\varepsilon.$$
- as $|g|\leq1$, you have $g(t)\in[-1,1]$ for all $t$. Taking $s=g(t)$ in $(*)$ you get
  $$
  |\,|g(t)|-P_\varepsilon(g(t))|<\varepsilon.
  $$
  As the inequality holds for all $t\in X$, you get that $$\tag{$**$}\||\,|g|-P_\varepsilon(g)\|_\infty<\varepsilon. $$
- Since $\mathcal A$ is an algebra that contains the constants you have, *for any polynomial $p=\sum_{j=0}^ma_jx^j$*, that 
  $$
  p(g)=a_0+a_1g+a_2g^2+\cdots+a_mg^m\in\mathcal A. 
  $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your message. I forgot to mention that $\mathcal{A}$ also separates the points of $X$, which would not be true of your example (?).

Comment: Just to make sure that I did not make a mistake in posing my question. I am referring to corollary 5.11 in this document [link](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/2010/3103_handout_5.pdf)

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: That's great. Thank you so much. I did, in fact, think in the wrong direction. Thank you for clearing that up.